# Does a nidui expire automatically?

Tags: shulchan-aruch, cherem

Shulchan Aruch YD [334:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.334.1) sets out the basic position that a nidui lasts 30 days after which it can be extended if the problem persists. It has to be specifically extended in order to continue in force. Therefore, if nobody does anything on the 30th day, all returns to normal.

But [334:27](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.334.27) suggests that a nidui continues in force even after 30 days, until it is specifically revoked. Therefore, if nobody does anything on the 30th day, the nidui continues.

Which one am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first case refers to where the *nidui* was made for a specific time period, for instance 30 days. Such a *nidui* expires automatically.

The second *nidui* was made without specifying a time period. Such a *nidui* needs to be explicitly revoked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and this is what I wondered. But then why does YD 334 go into such detail about the default length of a nidui as 30 days (and how, outside Israel, the default length is 7 days) in fact there's no such thing as a 'default length' at all because it has to be specified?

Comment: @zarka They are two subtly different ideas. One is the default length that the court ought to impose (thirty days or seven days) which it ought to specify when it makes the imposition. But that doesn't mean that practically the court could not impose a different length, or in fact without any explicit length at all, if it chose to.

Comment: Sorry to return to this, but the Rema seems to say at YD 334:24 that "every cherem and nidui that has not been released - even if its time has been exceeded and [the subject] has mended his ways - even then it is not released until [the authorities] explicitly release it". This must mean that even a time-limited nidui continues in force until specifically ended, so seems to conflict with 334:1? Can you advise further?

Comment: He doesn’t say that ‘its time has been exceeded’, just that the subject has been in nidui ‘for a long time’. Again, I assume that he’s not talking over there about a time-limited nidui.